# OpenStack command-line clients on macOS - keystone: command not found

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip, openstack, keystone

I followed [Install the OpenStack command-line clients](http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/common/cli_install_openstack_command_line_clients.html) on Mac 10.11.5

> To install the clients on a Linux, Mac OS X, or Microsoft Windows
>   system, use pip. It is easy to use, ensures that you get the latest
>   version of the clients from the Python Package Index, and lets you
>   update or remove the packages later on.

I wish to change password with [user-password-update](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/cli_examples.html)

after installing keystone, command is not found. Howto invoke keystone?

```
$ keystone
-bash: keystone: command not found
```

Here the details what I did and how my system looks like

```
$ pip install python-keystoneclient
(..)
Successfully installed Babel-2.3.4 debtcollector-1.6.0 funcsigs-1.0.2 iso8601-0.1.11 keystoneauth1-2.9.0 monotonic-1.1 msgpack-python-0.4.7 netaddr-0.7.18 netifaces-0.10.4 oslo.config-3.13.0 oslo.i18n-3.8.0 oslo.serialization-2.11.0 oslo.utils-3.16.0 pbr-1.10.0 positional-1.1.1 pyparsing-2.1.5 python-keystoneclient-3.2.0 pytz-2016.6.1 requests-2.10.0 rfc3986-0.3.1 six-1.10.0 stevedore-1.16.0 wrapt-1.10.8

$ pip show -f python-keystoneclient
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: python-keystoneclient
Version: 3.2.0
Summary: Client Library for OpenStack Identity
Home-page: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-keystoneclient
Author: OpenStack
Author-email: openstack-dev@lists.openstack.org
Installer: pip
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: oslo.i18n, oslo.utils, six, requests, oslo.serialization, positional, keystoneauth1, debtcollector, oslo.config, pbr, stevedore
Classifiers:
  Environment :: OpenStack
  Intended Audience :: Information Technology
  Intended Audience :: System Administrators
  License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
  Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux
  Programming Language :: Python
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
Files:
  keystoneclient/__init__.py
  (...)
  python_keystoneclient-3.2.0.dist-info/pbr.json
  python_keystoneclient-3.2.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
Entry-points:
  [keystoneclient.auth.plugin]
  admin_token = keystoneclient.auth.token_endpoint:Token
  password = keystoneclient.auth.identity.generic:Password
  token = keystoneclient.auth.identity.generic:Token
  v2password = keystoneclient.auth.identity.v2:Password
  v2token = keystoneclient.auth.identity.v2:Token
  v3oidcpassword = keystoneclient.contrib.auth.v3.oidc:OidcPassword
  v3password = keystoneclient.auth.identity.v3:Password
  v3scopedsaml = keystoneclient.contrib.auth.v3.saml2:Saml2ScopedToken
  v3token = keystoneclient.auth.identity.v3:Token
  v3unscopedadfs = keystoneclient.contrib.auth.v3.saml2:ADFSUnscopedToken
  v3unscopedsaml = keystoneclient.contrib.auth.v3.saml2:Saml2UnscopedToken
$ echo $PYTHONPATH 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

PYTHONPATH is also set. Howto get Python modules in path, execute the commands on Terminal?

Answer (score 3):

[Python-keystone client](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/OpenStackClients#python-keystoneclient) is deprecated, I suspect that's the issue: if you installed it on a new system, the executable is not there. You should install openstack-client instead.

`# pip install python-openstackclient`

Comment: What's wrong? keystone as a stand-alone client is not distributed anymore. Check http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/common/cli-install-openstack-command-line-clients.html, it's not there anymore. The python-keystoneclient on pip is just a library